# Angular CSS does not show, even if I can find className applied in Developer Web Tools Console

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

**Hello and thank you for reading my question:**

I am trying to style creating Divs and applying classes to them.

The code is, index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Integrar</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r81/three.js"></script>
  <!-- AMI -->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ami.js/0.0.22/ami.min.js"></script>
  INDEX HTML
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

And my AppComponent:

```
import {AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

declare var AMI: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    /* globals AMI*/

// element to contain the progress bar
    var container;
    container = document.getElementById('container');

// instantiate the loader
    var loader;
    loader = new AMI.VolumeLoader(container);

    var t2;
    t2 = ['36444280', '36444294', '36444308', '36444322', '36444336'];
    var files;
    files = t2.map(function (v) {
      return 'https://cdn.rawgit.com/FNNDSC/data/master/dicom/adi_brain/' + v;
    });
    loader
      .load(files)
      .then(function () {
        // merge files into clean series/stack/frame structure
        var series = loader.data[0].mergeSeries(loader.data);
        loader.free();
        loader = null;

        // series/stacks/frames are ready to be used
        window.console.log(series);

        // Display some content on the DOM
        var seriesIndex = 1;
        for (var mySeries of series) {
          var seriesDiv = document.createElement('div');
          seriesDiv.className += 'indent';
          seriesDiv.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div> SERIES (' + seriesIndex + '/' + series.length + ')</div>');
          seriesDiv.insertAdjacentHTML(
            'beforeend',
            '<div class="series"> numberOfChannels: ' + mySeries.numberOfChannels + '</div>'
          );

          container.appendChild(seriesDiv);

          // loop through stacks
          var stackIndex = 1;
          for (var myStack of mySeries.stack) {
            var stackDiv = document.createElement('div');
            stackDiv.className += 'indent';
            stackDiv.insertAdjacentHTML(
              'beforeend',
              '<div> STACK (' + stackIndex + '/' + mySeries.stack.length + ')</div>'
            );
            stackDiv.insertAdjacentHTML(
              'beforeend',
              '<div class="stack"> bitsAllocated: ' + myStack.bitsAllocated + '</div>'
            );

            seriesDiv.appendChild(stackDiv);

            // loop through frames
            var frameIndex = 1;
            for (var myFrame of myStack.frame) {
              var frameDiv = document.createElement('div');
              frameDiv.className += 'indent';
              frameDiv.insertAdjacentHTML(
                'beforeend',
                '<div> FRAME (' + frameIndex + '/' + myStack.frame.length + ')</div>'
              );
              frameDiv.insertAdjacentHTML(
                'beforeend',
                '<div class="frame"> instanceNumber: ' + myFrame.instanceNumber + '</div>'
              );

              stackDiv.appendChild(frameDiv);
              frameIndex++;
            }

            stackIndex++;
          }

          seriesIndex++;
        }
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        window.console.log('oops... something went wrong...');
        window.console.log(error);
      });

  }


}
```

Also the AppComponent template:

```
    <div id="container"></div>
LOADER html
```

And the AppComponent styles:

```
body{
  font-family: source-code-pro, sans-serif;
  color:#F9F9F9;
  background-color: #353535
}

.indent{
  padding-left: 8px;
}

.series{
  color: #F44336;
}

.stack{
  color:#8BC34A;
}

.frame{
  color:#FFEB3B;
}
```

So then the result is:
[image]

As far as I understand, I assume that first loads index.html, then the AppComponent and finally its template and CSS.

So if that is true, I tried to change the code, because of I first had the code implemented in ngOnInit, and then I tried as you can see in the code I posted, to use ngAfterViewInit, because I though it would wait until template and style load, and then would execute the code.

Doc: https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

It results that I can not get the CSS working. I tried to debug, and for example I can select the divs by className, so then the code itself is being applied:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('indent');
HTMLCollection(7) [div.indent, div.indent, div.indent, div.indent, div.indent, div.indent, div.indent]0: div.indent1: div.indent2: div.indent3: div.indent4: div.indent5: div.indent6: div.indentlength: 7__proto__: HTMLCollection
```

In addition, the result should be:
[image]

Could you help me, please???

Comment: It happens in Angular due to View Encaptulation (You can read https://angular.io/guide/component-styles before you start writing CSS for Angular Component).